# Debugging ASP.NET 5 App in VS Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug an App in Visual Studio Code. I created the project with:

```
yo aspnet //Empty App named myApp
cd "myApp"
dnu restore
dnu build
dnx kestrel
```

Well fortunately, it runs on `http://localhost:5001` but I need to `Ctrl-C` and rebuild every time. Now, debugging this through VS Code, I have the `launch.json` file on `.vscode` folder which has a line:

```
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
        "program": "app.js",
```

Now, I donot have any app.js on the project. How am I supposed to debug this app?

Command section of my `launch.json` is:

```
  "commands": {
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --config hosting.ini",
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --config hosting.ini"
  },
```

Hosting.ini:

```
server.urls=http://localhost:5000
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently ASP.NET 5 debugging is not supported on any platform, including running ASP.NET 5 on Mono on OS X and Linux. ASP.NET 5 applications are compiled using the Roslyn compiler, not the Mono compiler, and no debug information is being emitted. Visual studio code team hope to provide support for this scenario in an upcoming release.

In visual studio code the supported debugging scenarios are: Node.js based applications, supported on Linux, OS X, and Windows. Debugging of C# applications running on Mono is supported on Linux and OS X.

You can read more on: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging

Answer (score 0):

You can't debug ASP.NET 5 with VS Code Preview. ASP.NET 5 debugging support will be added later.